# JSON Array limit ¿sixty objects?

Tags: arrays, json, limit, jsonpath

I'm working with Twitter API and i have checked that json doesn't recognize arrays of more than sixty members.

I have check this issue with this tool: http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

If i put sixty objects in the array, it stops parsing the json, for example if you query $..results[*] (although it's valid). Any clues about this issue?

The json with only one object in the array

```
{"completed_in":0.138,"max_id":249066208408788992,"max_id_str":"249066208408788992","next_page":"?page=2&max_id=249066208408788992&q=bezoya%20OR%20lanjar%EF%BF%BD&lang=es&rpp=100","page":1,"query":"bezoya+OR+lanjar%EF%BF%BD","refresh_url":"?since_id=249066208408788992&q=bezoya%20OR%20lanjar%EF%BF%BD&lang=es","results":[{"created_at":"Wed, 19 Sep 2012 14:58:39 +0000","from_user":"villarroya093","from_user_id":781564459,"from_user_id_str":"781564459","from_user_name":"Javier Villarroya","geo":null,"id":248435942728290304,"id_str":"248435942728290304","iso_language_code":"es","metadata":{"result_type":"recent"},"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2550477368\/IMG-20120824-WA002_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2550477368\/IMG-20120824-WA002_normal.png","source":"&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter&quot;&gt;Twitter for BlackBerry\u00ae&lt;\/a&gt;","text":"RT @Xarlyfrasno: @villarroya093 #villarroyarules\nBeba agua mineral Bezoya, entra por la boca y sale..... muy bien de precio.","to_user":null,"to_user_id":0,"to_user_id_str":"0","to_user_name":null}],"results_per_page":100,"since_id":0,"since_id_str":"0"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely is a limit set by the creator of the tool. These limits would be in place to prevent users from stressing the server with very large datasets.